# Periodic functions of arbitrary groups

Tags: group-theory, periodic-functions

Periodic functions from $\mathbb{R}$ are frequently studied.  Also from $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.  It would seem possible to define periodicity for functions from an arbitrary group $G$ to any set $S$ but I cannot easily find much discussion of periodicity in these more general contexts.

If the group is Abelian with the operation $+$ then the definition could be identical:

$$\exists t \in G \ \ \forall x \in G \ \ f(x + t) = f(x)$$

Of course, it will not necessarily be possible to choose a canonical period hence we may need to talk of "a period" rather than "the period".

For a non-Abelian group, we may need to distinguish left and right perodicity.

$$\exists t \in G \ \ \forall x \in G \ \ f(t x) = f(x)$$

$$\exists t \in G \ \ \forall x \in G \ \ f(x t) = f(x)$$

Have I just not searched well enough?

Is this property usually given a different name in these more general contexts?

No one finds it interesting?

Comment: I wonder if https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform_on_finite_groups is the sort of thing you have in mind.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks, that  is certainly worth reading.

Comment: Connected to  [induced representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_representation)